# ConTeXt - Binding Offset

Tags: context, context-mkiv

In LaTeX, the geometry package allowed me to specify a binding offset (an amount by which the content area of each page was shifted away from the binding) for book layout. 
I'm very new to ConTeXt and I've been trying to replicate this feature without success. What is the proper way to do this in ConTeXt?

Here's an example, in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=1in, left=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, bindingoffset=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum
 \lipsum
 \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `horoffset` (horizontal offset) parameter of `\setuplayout` does that. The exact translation of your example will be:

```
\setuplayout
  [
    cutspace=1in,
    backspace=1in,
    topspace=1in,
    bottomspace=1in,
    horoffset=0.5in,
  ]


\showframe % to visualize the layout

\usemodule[ipsum]

\starttext
\ipsum
\stoptext
```